# how to find the owner of user and group from user HDFS

Tags: linux, permissions, group, ownership, hdfs

we can grant the permissions as hdfs user for hive as the following

```
su hdfs
$ hdfs dfs -chown hive:2098
```

but how to do the opposite way?

in order to verify the owner of hive and hive group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute the sample command `ls`

```
 hdfs dfs -ls /path
```

And from [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#ls) this is expected result:

> For a file returns stat on the file with the following format:

```
permissions number_of_replicas userid groupid filesize modification_date modification_time filename
```

> For a directory it returns list of its direct children as in Unix. A
>   directory is listed as:

```
permissions userid groupid modification_date modification_time dirname
```